# In sublime3, how to override Anaconda plugin settings for current project?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublime-anaconda

I use sublime 3 for python coding, with plugin Anaconda for format checking. But when I read others' codes, I don't need this function, because the whole file is full of format error which I don't care about but the Anaconda lint bothers me. So I would like close the function for this "project" (not current file), what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the state Anaconda linter using the `anaconda_linting` setting.

```
"anaconda_linting": false
```

Working with [projects](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/projects.html) gives you more refined control where you want to use the linter and where not. For instance, you could disable the linter in your [global settings](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/anaconda_settings/#toc_1) and enable it for [specific projects](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/anaconda_settings/#toc_2).

Comment: I have another question, does `pep8_autoformat` support project settings? why setting `"autoformat_on_save": false` in `.sublime-project` doesn't work